# For what value of 'a' does the following system of equations have infinite solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations, systems-of-equations

For what value of a does the following system of equations have infinite solutions?

```
   2x - 3y + z  = 0
   x + ay +2z = 0
   x + y  - z   = 0
```

How do you determine from equations alone whether with a or not the system represents infinite solutions? Would there have to be some sort of rearranging or from observation do you just look for some sort of pattern like one equation is double the other?

Comment: are you familiar with determinants?

Comment: You can do Gauss elimination to bring the system to what people call echelon form. The system will have infinitely many solutions if the echelon form has equations that are $0=0$  and no equation of the form $K=0$, where $K$ is different from zero.

Comment: I am familar with determinants. Would it not be an issue to use gauss elimination with 'a' being an unknown?

Comment: The only way that a parameter (like $a$) can obstruct Gauss elimination is if you ever need to divide by some coefficient that depends on that parameter and can be zero for some values and different from zero for some other values. You can either, use different pivots that don't depend on the parameter, if those are available. If not, then you can distinguish cases. If what you need to divide by is non-zero, you divide and keep going. If it is zero, put a zero there and find the next pivot.

Comment: It will be better to use Gauss Elimination. But you can write the system of equations as $Ax=0$ and for which values of $a$ the determinant is singular.

Comment: Find the values of $a$ for which $3$ columns become Linearly dependent. But the easiest way is to use Gauss Elimination.

Comment: I want to find 'a' first and then solve after using either Gauss or Gauss-jordan. What do you mean by write the equations as Ax = 0? And are you suggesting I guess the values and keep checking until the determinant is equal to 0?

Comment: In my case I am dealing with three equations but if for example it was two equations, there is a way of just observing and seeing if one equation is double the other or not as a result of giving value to a

Comment: You can use the last equation to eliminate $x$ from the first and second equations, for example. You get $\begin{cases}0x-5y+3z&=0\\0x+(a-1)y+3z&=0\\x+y-z&=0\end{cases}$. Next you can use the first equation to eliminate $z$ from the second equation (and from the third too, but this won't be needed). We get $\begin{cases}0x-5y+3z&=0\\0x+(a+4)y+0z&=0\\x+y-z&=0\end{cases}$. If $a\neq 4$, then you are forced to have $y=0$ from the second equation, then $z=0$ from the first and $x=0$ from the third. If $a=4$, then $y$ can take any value and you get from its values for $z$ and $x$.

Comment: I don't understand what your method of eliminating x is and why you are getting what you get for the first two equations. And what is it that makes you decide that with a being 4, the system of equations does in fact have infinite solution

Comment: Review Gauss elimination. If you subtract the last equation from the first and from the second, then the resulting first and second equations don't have $x$. In general Gauss elimination adds a multiple of one equation to another. In this case the factor is $-1$. In general the factor is chosen such that the coefficient of the variable becomes zero.

Comment: And without elimination, how would you have gone about finding the value of 'a' required to make the system have infinite solutions?

Comment: How do you work out determinant with an a that is unknown?

Comment: @Boxwood after finding a's value, is it possible through elimination to reach infinite solution

Comment: With $a=-4$ (I think I mistyped $4$ above), the second equation in the last system becomes $0=0$. Therefore, you can give $y$ any value you want. With this value of $y$ you get a single value for $z$ from the first equation and with these $y$ and $z$ you get a unique value for $x$ from the third equation. Therefore, there are infinitely many solutions. One for each choice for the value of $y$.

Comment: @Boxwood does infinitely many solutions ever include the identity matrix, if you were to get the identity matrix after elimination would that be normal in terms of still having infinitely many solutions